# Send data of IFrameElement to Flutter Web App

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web

I have an HTML file with javascript, that opens an external payment form, process the data and send a JSON response (See image). In flutter web I have already render it using IFrameElement. But I can't get the data sent from the form (IFrameElement) to the Flutter web app.

[image: Form render with iFrameElement]

In mobile app it works perfect with webviews and send JSON data with JS and postMessage channel. But in flutter web it does not work

It's possible in web app with IFrameElement?

I would expect the form response data (iFrameElement) to be sent to the flutter web app for processing this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to events from iframe like this.

```
<script>
    var channel = new MessageChannel();
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    iframe.addEventListener("load",(event) => {
      channel.port1.onmessage = onMessage;
      iframe.contentWindow.postMessage("", "*", [channel.port2]);
    })
   const onMessage = (e) => {
   parent.postMessage(e.data.eventType, '*');
   } 
</script>
```

*Now you can listen like this.*

```
html.window.onMessage.listen((event) {
      
      });
```

[Here is the example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hupg.png)

Comment: Please don't add code as Screenshots, instead copy the code to a script snippet :)